# Split string in parts by minus and plus in R

Tags: r, split, substr

I want to split this string:
test = "-1x^2+3x^3-x^8+1-x"
...into parts by plus and minus characters in R. My goal would be to get:
"-1x^2" "+3x^3" "-x^8" "+1" "-x"

This didn't work:

```
strsplit(test, split = "-")
strsplit(test, split = "+")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can provide a regular expression in `strsplit`, where we use `?=` to lookahead to find the plus or minus sign, then split on that character. This will allow for the character itself to be retained rather than being dropped in the split.

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=.)(?=[+])|(?<=.)(?=[-])",perl = TRUE)

# [1] "-1x^2" "+3x^3" "-x^8"  "+1"    "-x"
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the logic was. My understanding is that there is a SO rule against code only answers.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
> strsplit(test, split = "(?<=.)(?=[+-])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
[1] "-1x^2" "+3x^3" "-x^8"  "+1"    "-x"
```

where `(?<=.)(?=[+-])` captures the spliter that happens to be in front of `+` or `-`.

Comment: Ditto on my comment to Andrew.

Answer (score 5):

This uses gsub to search for any character followed by + or - and inserts a semicolon between the two characters.  Then it splits on semicolon.

```
s <- "-1x^2+3x^3-x^8+1-x"
strsplit(gsub("(.)([+-])", "\\1;\\2", s), ";")[[1]]
## [1] "-1x^2" "+3x^3" "-x^8"  "+1"    "-x"
```

Answer (score 4):

In your examples, you use `strsplit` with a plus and a minus sign which will split on every encounter.

You could assert that what is directly to the left is not either the start of the string or `+` or `-`, while asserting `+` and `-` directly to the right.

```
(?<!^|[+-])(?=[+-])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookabehind assertion

  - `^` Start of string
  - `| Or`   - `[+-]` Match either `+` or `-` using a character class
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(?=` Positive lookahead assertion

  - `[+-]` Match either `+` or `-`
- `)` Close lookahead

As the pattern uses lookaround assertions, you have to use `perl = T` to use a perl style regex.

**Example**

```
test <- "-1x^2+3x^3-x^8+1-x"
strsplit(test, split = "(?<!^|[\\s+-])(?=[+-])", perl = T)
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
[1] "-1x^2" "+3x^3" "-x^8"  "+1"    "-x"
```

See a online [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOLqyS1uETBRldBSdewIs5I27gizli3Is5C21C3QokLqKy4ICezRAOkSkcBzFawVVDSsLdRjKuJ1taN1dSwtwXTSjoKBalFOUDZEE2u//8B).

---

If there can also not be a space to the left, you can write the pattern as

```
(?<!^|[\\s+-])(?=[+-])
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOJMio/1).